# How do I abort building the list for tab completion without losing the command?

Tags: bash, tab-completion

```
some_very_long_command_line --arg1 --arg2=555 --arg4 ... ... ... && <now Tab pressed>
(Now it works. I want to cancel before the following message)
Display all 6936 possibilities? (y or n)
```

How to about longish search for Tab completion, but not lose the command?

If just press Ctrl+C it will abort, but also not save the command to history.

Answer (score 1):

Just press backspace.  The y/n request goes away and returns your cursor to the command line you were typing.

Comment: It also works from within the --More-- listing of results.

Comment: No. I want to cancel before it shows "Display all possibilities" message.

Comment: I understand now.  You want to cancel it while it's actually searching the filesystem to compile the list of possible completions.  Hmmm... I can't see that being possible.

Comment: It is possible (Ctrl+C). But the incomplete command is lost (unless use mouse).

Answer (score 0):

Just press `n`.

That should cancel it.

Comment: No, it does not listen for "n" or "backspace" until it walked the filesystem and build the list.

Comment: @Vi: If I press tab, the prompt "Display all x possibilities? (y or n)" appears almost instantly for me even when x is a few thousand.

Comment: @Denis: If _you_ press Tab. Some aren't as lucky :(

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [here](https://serverfault.com/a/265101/337411).

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. It will stop the completion and go back to your command line without losing the current command.

Comment: When it's a stuck FUSE filesystem, neither ^C nor ^\ helps...